# Why does Visual Studio suggest "TODO: set large fields to null."?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When writing VB.NET in Visual Studio (2010 at least), if you create a class that implements `IDisposable` the IDE will generate this skeleton for you:

```
' IDisposable
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        End If

        ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
        ' TODO: set large fields to null.
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
End Sub
```

If I understand garbage collection correctly, setting fields to null would serve no purpose.* But why would Visual Studio recommend it then?

**Assuming that you aren't holding live references to the object that is being disposed, which would be strange.*

Comment: You can't assume that no one holds live references to an IDisposable during Dispose.  Someone can call Dispose regardless of whatever references other objects have.

Comment: @Jerry Yes it's possible but it would (almost certainly) be a bug, and probably a bigger problem than large objects not getting GC'd.

Comment: If you have control over the usage of the class in question, then it's true that you should try to ensure that it's being used correctly.  But VS has no way of knowing whether you are writing something intended to be used by other people.  Their bugs aren't your responsibility, but what you do during Dispose *is*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is in general very little to admire about this auto-generated code.  The disposable pattern has been obsolete for the past 10 years, elegantly replaced by critical finalizers in .NET 2.0.  But not completely gone, several handfuls of .NET classes from the 1.0 days implement it.  And when you derive from such a class then you're stuck with having override the `Dispose(Boolean)` method.  Sadly the VB.NET editor isn't smart enough to detect this corner-case.

Best way to categorize the advice is to not label it as correct but as "not wrong".  As long as a VB.NET programmer blindly follows the advice they'll never get in trouble.  Nothing wrong with that.

The "set large fields to null" advice also thoroughly falls in the "not wrong" category.  It will not often make any difference, it is however technically possible that the "large object" lives in an earlier GC generation.  Which is somewhat likely to happen when it was allocated late, long after the disposable object was created.  Setting it to `Nothing` then allows the GC to release it earlier and the program will run leaner.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: if your last paragraph is true though, then why not set any large object to 'null' before it falls out of scope?  As an example I mean if you had a very large string declared and populated in a sub - get to the bottom of the sub - do I set the string to null?  The general advice is not to do that I thought - or is it?

Comment: Hmya, scope does not have much to do with exactly when an object gets collected.  Especially so when the scope is the Dispose() method.  Always better when you have a good idea when objects are eligible for collection and always better when that happens *really* quickly after the Dispose() method runs.  But if you have no real idea then you'll never have to be sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Someone might hold a reference to the object being `Disposed` for any amount of time. But as the implementer of the `IDisposable` class, you know that you don't need the large object after `Dispose()`. To allow the large object to be collected as soon as possible, set it to null.

Comment: however the comment refers to a 'field' not an object - what does this mean exactly?  I think that you make a new null field that needs to be collected, and the old field is just left as garbage to be collected, same as it would anyway.